ArangoDB _key value is not auto incrementing correctly in cluster
I'm using ArangoDB 3.7.2-1 in a cluster setup. For all collections, we set Number of shards: 1.
For query load time consideration, I moved old data from collections to different server, so the query wouldn't scan the entire rows from beginning.
I didn't realize the problem until I made mirroring data to postgreSQL with unique arango_key constraint.
After several months passed, when I attempted to moved the second batch of archiving, the postgreSQL threw error:
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "{collection}_archived_arango_id_unique"

After confirming that the content were different between the 2 servers with the same _key, I checked the maximum value of the _key of the original server.
FOR c IN collectionName
COLLECT AGGREGATE maxk = MAX(c._key)
RETURN {max_coll_key: TO_NUMBER(maxk)}

The result was 957636395 (957.636.395) while the conflicted row _key was 1487518966 (1.487.518.966). How come the maximum _key is less than the generated one? Is it because of the cluster setup?
I really don't understand the how it happened.
Is it related with the github issue?
